# CSS arrow with border add box shadow

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip with arrow and arrow border, but I need the arrow to get also the box shadow of the tooltip how I can do this?

I need a cross-browser solution. I can't use CSS filter.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1.5px 4px 0px rgba(170, 174, 181, 0.45);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(6px);
          transform: translateX(6px);
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0);
  border-right-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-width: 7px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
 <div class="arrow_box">
  <p>tooltip</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://codepen.io/ryanmcnz/pen/JDLhu

Comment: Dont make the arrow with border(triangle).. just make it a regular rectangle and rotate it and apply shadow and keep its z-index low

Comment: Can you add an answer with an example, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution of your problem can be solved, like the one posted here:
https://codepen.io/ryanmcnz/pen/JDLhu

Basically:
1. Create a square (::after), rotate it and add box shadow.
2. Create a second square (::before) that overlaps the box shadow casted inside the balloon.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.triangle::after{
    z-index: -10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    left:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
.triangle::before{
    z-index: 10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    left:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle">This is a CSS3 triangle with a proper box-shadow!</div>
```

Comment: I can't see a border color in the arrow. Can you please take my example and modify it?

Comment: @ng2user take a look please. You can declare border color also inside border property. Example: "border: 1px solid #fff;". Another thing: If you are using Chrome to develop, press F12 and inspect element and play LIVE with your object's properties.

Comment: I saw this example before and tried it but I couldn't make it work

Comment: @ng2user is it good now? If yes, please take your time and understand it. It will help a lot more than a simple copy paste. Also, please don't forget to  upvote. I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: This looks nice on a plain white background like in the snippet, but when you have text or other elements under the tooltip, that negative z-index is making the arrow appear under them. And in fact the ::before element is not even needed if you're going to put a negative z-index on the ::after, this is what hides the shadow inside in the first place.

Comment: I agree @AsGoodAsItGets . Therefore for each `z-index` property in the CSS above, add `20 units`. Instead of `z-index: 10;`, you will have `z-index: 30;` for `z-index: -10;`, you will have `z-index: 10;`. And the code will still work. Cheers!

Comment: @besciualex I ended up using this solution which requires an extra element for the arrow, and doesn't rely on z-index: https://codepen.io/weaintplastic/pen/YWOQXB

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon this the other day and thought I will leave this here. My solution is a single element, only using one of the pseudo `:before` element and utilizing `clip-path`.

```css
:root {
  --shadowSize: 20px;
  --shadowColor: #f00;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--shadowSize) var(--shadowColor);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--shadowSize) var(--shadowColor);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  clip-path: polygon(
    calc(var(--shadowSize) * -1) calc(var(--shadowSize) * -1), 
    calc(100% + var(--shadowSize)) calc(var(--shadowSize) * -1), 
    calc(100% + var(--shadowSize)) calc(100% + var(--shadowSize))
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia excepturi et unde soluta accusamus dolorum. Architecto, a laborum. Unde impedit aliquam voluptatibus sed dignissimos mollitia nihil consectetur dolores accusamus recusandae?</div>
```

The `clip-path` or rotation of the `:before`-element has to be adjusted if you want to place the arrow on a different side of the box. The CSS also has to be adjusted if you want to use `box-shadow` offset, it's currently only calculating the actual size of it.

Example using SCSS: https://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/gOMvYOx

Comment: Could you make a Codepen version with the arrow on the left side? I can't figure out the clip path to fix that.

Comment: @Garconis I adjusted the linked codepen and added a `.box--left` modifier. Simply rotate the before pseudo element and you should be fine. You might want to include a padding all around to have the arrow be contained in the same box as the box itself.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution would be to remove the `box-shadow:` style from `.arrow_box` and add the following separately in your CSS file:

```
:host{
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1.5px 4px 0px rgba(170, 174, 181, 0.45));
}
```

This adds a shadow over your entire element.