# css: inset shadow around of an arrow

Tags: html, css

I design an arrow top of an ul box menu like this picture:

[image]

You can see, I set a border around of box:

```
border: .1rem solid rgba(228,234,248,.5);
```

but Is there a way to set a border around of arrow?

[image]

```
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fbfbfb;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 13.1rem;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of the entire menu box in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS arrow with border add box shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863785/css-arrow-with-border-add-box-shadow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no ways to set a border around the arrow as the triangle you made is itself a border. But there's a solution, you can overlay the triangles on each other like, this will give you a `border` effect around your triangle.

```css
div {
  position: relative; 
  /* make sure you use this else your elements will fly in the wild */
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 10px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
  border-left: 9px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```